# Data structure that stays sorted, allows log N insertion time, and can return the index of an element that I look for in log N

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, multiset

I want a data structure where I insert elements into it, and right after the insertion, it stays sorted and I find out the index of the element I just inserted in log N time.

I've tried using a vector and a multiset but neither satisfied both requirements.

**Vector:**

If I want to find the index of an element, I can do:

```
using namespace std;
vector<int>::iterator it = lower_bound(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), someElement);
int index = (it - myvec.begin());
```

However, the vector doesn't allow for O(log N) insertion time while remaining sorted. Sorting the vector after each insertion would be O(N log N) each time. I tried:

```
vector<int>::iterator it = lower_bound(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), someElement);
myvec.insert(it, someElement);
```

This finds the right location to insert the element, but the myvec.insert runs on O(N) time rather than O(log N) time.

**Multiset:**

The multiset allows me to insert and remain sorted, but where it lacks is getting the index of the element after insertion.

```
multiset<int>::iterator it = lower_bound(myset.begin(), myset.end(), someElement);
```

After using lower_bound, I cannot merely do

```
int index = (it - myset.begin());
```

like I would with a vector. Instead, a method I considered was:

```
int index = distance(myset.begin(), it);
```

However, distance runs on O(N) time instead of O(log N) time.

Is there a data structure or method that allows me to satisfy both requirements in log N time?

Comment: This is an "ordered vector" with `O(n)` insert time: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_set.html . The `O(log n)` for `std::set` is achieved mainly because elements can be rearranged without copying data. I don't think that's possible for a contiguous, ordered container.

Comment: I am looking for an ordered data structure with O(log N) insertion time rather than O(N).

Comment: What do you need the index for ?

Comment: @parktomatomi The container doesn't need to be contiguous, so it is possible using a modified binary search tree that keeps track of the number of nodes in each subtree. This can be updated easily and be used to find the index during traversal.

Answer (score 2):

Neither vector nor multiset can achieve the requirements.

A data structure that does achieve the requirements is a balanced binary search tree, that is augmented by storing the size of the sub tree in the nodes. Such augmented search tree is called an "Order statistic tree".

Although the ordered associative containers of the standard library are internally implemented using search trees, the standard library does not provide a generic tree  data structure that could be used to implement this.

Comment: Can you provide a link explaining the use of order statistic trees? Thanks

Comment: @WilsonDuan Here's one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree

Comment: GCC's [policy-based data structures](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/policy_data_structures.html) extension includes an implementation of this which might be useful.